How to Make React Skeleton Loader Responsive with Different Line Counts for Desktop and Mobile?
I'm currently working on a React project where I'm using react-loading-skeleton to implement loading skeletons. I would like to make the skeleton responsive so that it displays a different number of lines depending on the screen size. Specifically, I want to show:

3 lines on desktop screens
5 lines on mobile screens

This is to maintain the content's height and avoid any sudden layout shifts when the actual content loads.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
{loading ? (
  <SkeletonTheme baseColor="#222222" highlightColor="#000">
    <Skeleton height="24px" count={3} width="100%" borderRadius="4px" />
  </SkeletonTheme>
) : (
  <MyText>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Suscipit, dolor. Lorem ipsum 
    dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Suscipit, dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
    amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Suscipit, dolor?
  </MyText>
)}

How can I modify the skeleton loader to display 3 lines on desktop and 5 lines on mobile while maintaining the content's height to avoid jumping content?

Since you are wanting to control a prop value you'll need to check the view size outside the Skeleton component in order to pass in different count prop values.
Here's an example implementation that uses a window.resize listener to test the view is greater than a specified width.
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useIsViewWidth = (width = 0) => {
  const [innerWidth, setInnerWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setInnerWidth(window.innerWidth);
    };

    handleResize();

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize, true);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize, true);
    };
  }, []);

  return innerWidth > width;
};

const isDesktop = useIsViewWidth(768);

...

{loading ? (
  <SkeletonTheme baseColor="#222222" highlightColor="#000">
    <Skeleton
      height="24px"
      count={isDesktop ? 3 : 5} // <-- pass correct count value here
      width="100%"
      borderRadius="4px"
    />
  </SkeletonTheme>
) : (
  <MyText>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Suscipit, dolor. Lorem ipsum 
    dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Suscipit, dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
    amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Suscipit, dolor?
  </MyText>
)}


